# How to make template method called only once in Angular 7?

Tags: angular7

In Angular, when we call any method in interpolation like **{{ setId() }}** it will be called multiple times and hence not good way to do it(due to performance issue). In *AngularJs* we have ***{{ ::newMethod() }}*** way to do it. Is there any way(other than pure pipe) in Angular to call template method only once ?

Comment: You should avoid calling methods from your template because the method will be called every time change detection runs.

Comment: Thanks @RahulSingh for your quick response, but even if we avoid method call in template, we use getter as second solution, still it gets executed multiple times. So whats the alternative to it?

Comment: Have you seen this issue : [Provide one time binding possibility for better performance](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14033) from 2017

Comment: @Shree getter is nothing but a method , so the same problem will be replicated in case of getters too, you can try using change detection strategy or else you can try and put the method on ngOnInit that might help or as you mentioned try and use pure pipes

Comment: What do you want to accomplish by calling `setId()` in template? Maybe you can use `ngAfterViewInit` to call `setId()` after initing the template.

Comment: Hi @HarunYılmaz i just want to add uniquId to every generated component.

Comment: I think it will be helpful if you add your template and component code

Comment: If you want to give your components an uniquely generated ID, you should use a service that you call on the constructor or `ngOnInit`. You don't call functions in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid calling methods from your template because the method will be called every time change detection runs.

Try and use `OnPush` change detection strategy to avoid unnecessary checks

Something like this

```
import { Component,ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  // ...
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

Comment: Won't change a thing, the function will still be called at every change detection. In order for your solution to work, it means the change detection should run only once ... Which is either very difficult to do, or impossible.